# How do I see one Gmail status when in another Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, account-management

I have a main Gmail account that I use personally.  I've just created a new specific purpose account.  I'd like to be able to stay signed into my general account, but see the status (new mail count) of the other account so I know when to go read it, since it doesn't get much traffic right now.

Is there a way to do this in Gmail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few options that you can do.

- You can enable the multiple login from the [Google Account](https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/ManageAccount) page
- You can enable from your second account the Forwarding by adding a **forwarding e-mail** from Settings.

[image]

- You can enable the POP for all mail in your second account and then adding new account in your personal mail from **Settings** > **Accounts and Import**

[image]

I personally prefer the last option because you can easily add a new label for all your e-mails from the second account and even skipping the inbox.

Comment: I decided to go with the multiple login option, it  doesn't give me the status, but it does make it easier to switch and check.

Answer (score 1):

One option you could do is to add your new email account to your main Gmail account under Settings >> Accounts and Import >> Send mail from another address. Then, under the Labs options, enable the Multiple Inboxes feature. With Multiple Inboxes enabled, you could create an inbox pane that showed emails to your new email account with:

```
to:<insert new email address>
```

So, now you'd be able to see your emails to your main account, as well as see emails sent to your other account. The only downside to doing this is that the new inbox pane won't appear in your Priority Inbox view. The multiple inboxes only show up in the normal Inbox view.

Comment: I think I'll go with this once they get it to work with Priority Inbox.